# Kentico v9 transformation and Roles

Tags: kentico

I have an alert section pulling items with a repeater. My transformation pulls date and copy and displays them in UL tags.

I've been asked to make a change where a specific alert would only be seen by people is a specific group/role.

My thoughts were change the page type form with a check box. On the transformation side i would then need a conditional statement where the check box is true and the user is part of specific Role.

My transformation is currently an ASCX  and is as follows:

```
<li><%# Eval("Alert") %></li>
```

I imagine it being something like this

```
<% if ( checked = true && role = XX ) { <li>Eval("Alert")</li> } %>
```

I just can't figure out the conditional statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Text/XML transformation

```
{% if(checked == true && CurrentUser.IsInRole("MyRole")) {return "<li>" + Alert + "</li>"}  %}
```

ASCX

```
<%# If(CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.IsInRole("rolename", CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName) && Eval("checked") == true, "<li>" + Eval("Alert") + "</li>","") %>
```

Comment: Thanks Laura, this will help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to add some CSS class based on your condition:

```
<li class="<% if(Eval<bool>("FieldsName") &&
     CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.IsInRole("rolename", CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);) {"alert"} %>">
    ....
</li>
```

Having "alert" class added to your li, you can change visibility, colors or whatever you need for that item.

This approach requires ASPX transformation.

Comment: Thanks Roman,

I may use this approach for another last minute requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method CurrentUser.IsInRole(, )

I came up with something like:

```html
<%# (checked && CurrentUser.IsInRole("_everyone_", "corporate") ? Eval("DocumentName") : "empty") %>
```

David